# File Manager Module in DotNetNuke

Tags: file-manager, dotnetnuke, dnn9

I need a module to store files. The module should have different file sections and each section, file categories. I need users to have access to specific sections based on their user account and role. Categories are not standard and can be created by the administrator.

Is there a file manager module that covers this functionality (either free or paid), or should I develop a module from, scratch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at Evotiva User Files, this should meet your requirements: https://www.evotiva.com/products/dnn-user-files